# React - in which component should I do http requests?

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, react-router-v4

In my "`Home.js`" component I want to show a list of products that is fetched using http request (with axios). I also have a "`Product.js`" component where I would also need to fetch the product the same way. I'm not clear on the guidelines on where to put this kind of code.

If I put these requests in their respective components (Home and Product), then they have to be class components I guess? They can't be stateless component since the product data need to be stored in the components own state. And that data couldn't be accessed by the parent App.js, I guess? (I don't know if that matters though).

But if I would put all that stuff in the parent component, and pass it down to the components, it becomes a bit troublesome. I don't want to make all those requests on all pages, so I need to conditional check to see which is the current url. And I can't make use of `match.params` of react router to get the ":product" param. I started on some code where I make the requests in `App.js`, but it doesn't seem very smooth. I need to get the parameter called `:product`, and I suppose I could solve it by using more regular expressions:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {

    loading: false,
    product: [],
    products: []

  }

    componentWillMount() {

    const re = new RegExp('^/product');            

    if (window.location.pathname === '/' ){              // if url is '/', get products

            this.setState({loading: true})

            axios.get('/api/getproducts')
               .then(response => {

                this.setState({   
                    products: response.data,
                    loading: false
                })
            }))   
}
           // check if url begins with 'product', get product
else if  (re.test(window.location.pathname)){       

            // axios.get('/api/getproduct/' + match.params.product)   //need :product param
            // .then(response => {

        // })

    }

So, should I instead do data fetching in the components/routes where they need to be loaded, storing it in their own state?
```

I thought it was recommended to put all data at the top component. But in this case what would be the recommended way?

Answer (score 3):

Although it is up to you, I would say it is indeed better to make the requests on the higher order components, as long as they are relevant.

So in this case, I would say your best bet is doing the `getproducts` request in your Home component instead of the App. The reason for this is because the App tends to be the starting point of all components form the entire application (as it's name would suggest). For small apps this may not make a difference, but say you are making a bigger one with dozens upon dozens of components, each with their own necessary requests. It would be complete chaos if all those were in the App component.

Not to mention, if you are in the component that is supposed to be rendered in a certain URL, you don't have to worry about checking for that. If the relevant component is mounted the request will be made.

Now for the second part, making the `getproduct` request seems to make more sense in the Product component. Since it will probably fetch the data relevant to the product, is that correct?

So anyway, given the information mentioned in the post, I would suggest just something like this:

For the `Home.js` file:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      products: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    axios.get('/api/getproducts')
    .then(response => {

      this.setState({   
          products: response.data,
          loading: false
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { loading, products } = this.state
    if (loading) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }

    // Note: I am using product.id and product.name, but it really is whatever you are using to identify your different products
    // I have also made it in a way that will link to the product
    return (
      <ul>
        products.map(product =>
          <li>
            <Link to=`/${product.id}`>
               product.name
            </Link>
          </li>
        )
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

For the `Product.js` file:

```
export default class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      product: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    axios.get(`/api/getproduct/${this.props.match.params.product}`)
    .then(response => {

      this.setState({   
          product: response.data,
          loading: false
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { loading, product } = this.state
    if (loading) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }

    return (
     <div>
     {product.whatever}
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I guess this will probably be the best way, and the least complicated. Maybe it's most natural that the component does the request for its own data.

Comment: In this particular case I would say so.